# Equivalent relation of curves

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-analysis

Given two intervals $I=[a,b],J=[c,d]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and two continuous
functions $\boldsymbol{u}:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}%
:J\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d}$, we say that $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}%
$ are equivalent, and we write $\boldsymbol{u}\approx\boldsymbol{v}$, if there
exists an increasing function (possibly not strictly increasing)
$\phi:I\rightarrow J$ such that the smallest interval that contains
$\phi\left(  I\right)  $ is $J$, for every discontinuity point of $x\in I$ of
$\phi$, the interval $\left[  \phi_{-}\left(  x\right)  ,\phi_{+}\left(
x\right)  \right]  $ is contained in an interval $\left[  \tau_{1},\tau
_{2}\right]  \subseteq J$ on which $\boldsymbol{v}$ is constant, and
$\boldsymbol{u}(x)=\boldsymbol{v}(\phi(x))$ for all $x\in I$.

Prove that $\approx$ is an equivalent relation. Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: What have you done already? What are you supposed to verify for an equivalence relation?

Comment: I only did the reflexive part.For the symmetry and transitive part, I have no idea ?